# The scope of variable in inner anonymous method

Tags: c#, oop, closures

See the code

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        var AnonymousMethod = t.OuterMethod();
        AnonymousMethod("passedValue");
    }
     public delegate void SampleDelegate(string InputText);

     public SampleDelegate OuterMethod()
    {
        string outerValue="outerValue";
        return (x => {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(outerValue);
        });

    }
}
```

OutPut

```
Success  time: 0.02 memory: 33816 signal:0
passedValue
outerValue
```

Link to [Example](http://ideone.com/FFyKa3)

Normally the scope of variable `outerValue` would end after calling `t.OuterMethod()`. But in the case of using anonymous type, Console printed the output clearly  (`Console.WriteLine(outerValue)`) which means the scope of variable didn't end. What do actually the compiler do to determine its scope? Will it assign the scope of `Main` method to the variables used inside the anonymous method? I know how to use but don't know how it works. Please guide me?

**Edit**

> Suppose the anonymous method attached to an event. The event might be
>   executing a lot later. Then the variable would be in memory. rite? If
>   a lot of events assigned, a lot of memory!. Its a bad thing I suppose.
>   Did I make any mistake?

Comment: The variable is compiled into a closure for the anonymous method to use and keep hold of.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth then scope of a closure?

Comment: See Jon Skeet's answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope of the variable (the region of program text within which it is possible to refer to it without qualification) remains the same.

The "lifetime" of the variable is effectively extended: the lambda expression *captures* the variable. The compiler will have generated a private nested class for you, with that variable in - both the method and the delegate refer to the same instance of this nested class, and that instance won't be eligible for garbage collection until the method no longer refers to it and the delegate instance is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Suppose the anonymous method attached to an event. The event might be executing a lot later. Then the variable would be in memory. rite? If a lot of events assigned, a lot of memory!. Its a bad thing I suppose. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: please answer this question too.

Comment: @SubinJacob: Firstly, please give people a chance to address comments before prompting them further. Stack Overflow is not your own personal pool of servants. We have other things to do with our lives. But yes, this can be a cause for concern - but presumably you're only capturing the variables because you *need* them, which means it's an inherent problem in what you're trying to do, not in the C# implementation. (There *is* a problem in the C# implementation if multiple anonymous functions capture different variables fromt he same scope, but that's much more complicated.)

Comment: If you felt so, I'm deeply regretted. I didn't mean so. Thanks for yur answer.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous methods are compiled into their own classes. These classes have fields for each of the captured variables. The instance of the class is 'the scope'.

What variables are captured? All *top level* symbols.

For example.

```
Action a = () => this.ANumber;
```

`this` is captured.

```
int aNumber = this.ANumber;
Action a = () => aNumber;
```

Only `aNumber` is captured.

Comment: Well *sometimes* a new class is created. Not always though - it depends on whether there are any variables to be captured. When only `this` is captured, I believe the compiler simply creates an instance method for the anonymous function.

Comment: @JonSkeet Makes sense. Thanks for the knowledge - always a pleasure to receive your input.

Comment: Suppose the anonymous method attached to an event. The event might be executing a lot later. Then the variable would be in memory. rite? If a lot of events assigned, a lot of memory!. Its a bad thing I suppose. Did I make any mistake?

Comment: @SubinJacob The captured variables would take on the same lifetime as you would expect from an event subscription. Yes, you are right. Be careful though: unless you store a reference to the lambda, you may not be able to unsubscribe from the event!